# Service Fabric: removed actors and now upgrade fails

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to upgrade a Service Fabric application with a mix of stateful and stateless actors. I did some refactoring and so removed some actors I didn't need any more. Now, when I try to upgrade the application, I get the following error:

> Services must be explicitly deleted before removing their Service Types.

After thinking about it a little bit, I *think* I understand the trouble that could come from removed services and upgrades, but then what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the service instances before you can upgrade to a version that doesn't contain the removed service package. Either:

- In SF Explorer, navigate to the service and click Actions > Delete Service
- In PowerShell:

  ```
  Connect-ServiceFabricCluster
  Remove-ServiceFabricService -ServiceName fabric:/MyApp/MyService
  ```

**DO BE CAREFUL** - If you're deleting a stateful service you'll lose all its data. Always be sure to have a periodic backup of production data.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure this out, which is close to what you're suggesting here. I'd suggest deploying an upgrade without any dependencies on the services you want to delete. Once your upgrade succeeds, _then_ delete the services and re-deploy an upgrade with the services removed. This allows you to migrate away from the services you want to delete, while not breaking any other services that depend on those services.